# Handle Pan Gesture on UITableView cell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer, xcode9.1

I added [MARKRangeSlider](https://github.com/vadymmarkov/MARKRangeSlider) to UITableViewCell and its working as expected. While dragging handle, the table view controller is also popping up to previous view controller. How could I avoid or prevent the action of popping up?

I tried following code by adding delegate but failed to achieve the result.

```
 - (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
         // CGPoint velocity = [panGestureRecognizer  velocityInView:panGestureRecognizer.view];
         // return fabs(velocity.y) > fabs(velocity.x);
        CGPoint translation = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer translationInView:gestureRecognizer.view.superview];
        // if you want an NSString
        NSLog(@"gestureRecognizer-superview %@", NSStringFromClass([gestureRecognizer.view.superview class]) );
        return fabs(translation.x) > fabs(translation.y);
    }


- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldBeRequiredToFailByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer{
    if (otherGestureRecognizer == leftPanRecognizer) {
        return YES;
    }
    if (otherGestureRecognizer == rightPanRecognizer) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Its intermittent issue. Please let me know how to deal it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution,

In `UITableViewController` or `UIViewController` which has `UITableView` has to *disable* `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` in `viewDidAppear` and in **same** Controller developer has to *enable* `interactivePopGestureRecognizer` in `viewWillDisAppear` . Hope it helps.